# Метод Delete. Обертка над массивом. Неверный алгоритм

Tags: java

У меня есть некий класс, который является оберткой над массивом. Этот класс называется хранилищем моих элементов. Итак, в этом классе есть массив моих элементов, и методы `add`, `replace`, `delete`, которые занимаются добавлением, заменой и удалением соответственно. Проблема в методе `delete`,- мне нужно найти элемент по значению `id` (это значение есть у каждого элемента) и удалить его, потом сместить все элементы влево на один элемент.

```
  public void delete(String id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].getId().equals(id))
            this.items[i] = null;
    }
    System.arraycopy(items,position,items,position-1,1);
}
```

items - это массив элементов.
У меня получилось довольно кривовато, может подскажет кто, что не так ?

Comment: Возьмите коллекцию, так будет проще и правильнее. Массив - статичен, не может быть расширен или уменьшен. System.arraycopy каждый раз создает копию массива. А коллекция может быть расширена без пересоздания

Comment: Мне по задаче нужно именно массив использовать. Задание такое.

Comment: Ваше значение id это index массива? (порядковый номер элемента в массиве)

Comment: нет, это уникальный ключ, который я создаю через UUID. Тоже заморочка условия

Comment: А Ваша [Integer.valueOf(id)] это вы из UUID получаете id? если у вас в массиве id это порядковый номер в массиве тогда можно избавиться от цикла

Comment: Ну или просто дайте больше кода

Comment: я переделал условие в if, чтоб было понятнее что я хочу получить. Вот      if (items[i].getId().equals(id))   
                this.items[i] = null;

Comment: обновил в шапке, посмотрите. Я думаю теперь проблема осталась с arrayCopy у меня

Comment: Это не работающий код, переменная `position` не определена, либо если она определена за рамками метода, то не меняется в нем, а по логике должна.

Comment: System.arraycopy(Object src,int srcPos,Object dest,int destPos,int length) копирует массив из src в dest начиная с позиции srcPos длинной length и пишет с позиции destPos. Т.Е. (src,0,dest,1,5) скопирует 5 элементов из src в dest и запишет их начиная с позиции 1 и dest.length будет =6 а dest[0] ,будет null

Comment: Вы пытаетесь уменьшить таким образом массив ? я так понимаю ?

Comment: iksuy, я для этого и назвал вопрос Неверный алгоритм, потому что нуждаюсь в помощи как исправить, что добавить нужно к логике.

Comment: Tr1nks, я лишь пытаюсь выполнить предназначение метода и условие задачи, которое гласит что метод delete должен находить элемент в массиве по id и удалять его, потом сдвигать массив влево на одну ячейку

Comment: еще одно уточнение, есть ограничение на то что такой элемент в массиве может быть только один ??

Comment: да, конечно он один, id это же уникальное поле у каждого элемента, то есть с таким id который передан в аргументе метода , есть только один элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
 public void delete(String id) throws NoSuchElementException{
    Item[] out = new Item[items.length - 1];
    int index = IntStream.range(0, items.length).filter(i -> items[i].getId().equals(id)).findFirst().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
    System.arraycopy(items, 0, out, 0, index);
    System.arraycopy(items, index + 1, out, index, items.length - index);
    items = out;
}
```

P.S. возможно я немного напутал с индексами при копировании но логика такова : ищем в стриме индекс нашего элемента, потом в два приема копируем старый массив в новый "вырезая" удаляемый элемент.

P.P.S  без стрима

```
 public void delete(String id){
    Item[] out = new Item[items.length - 1];
    int index =-1;
    for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        if(items[i].getId().equals(id)){
            index=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.arraycopy(items, 0, out, 0, index);
    System.arraycopy(items, index + 1, out, 0, items.length - index);
    items = out;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, я попробую так сделать. Честно говорю с стримами не очень знаком, но попробую разобраться

Comment: стрим можно заменить на простой цикл

Comment: Почему бы не сдвинуть все элементы на один влево, если индекс не последний? В приведенном выше примере без стрима если цикл не найдет нужный элемент по id - у меня для вас плохие новости

Comment: Что Вы хотите получить в результате сдвига? уменьшатся все индексы на 1 но размер массива не изменится и искомый элемент не будет удален. Да там будет брошена ошибка о выходе за пределы, но в варианте со стримом я тоже кидаю ошибку при отсутствии элемента.

Answer (score 0):

> delete,- мне нужно найти элемент по значению id (это значение есть у каждого элемента) и удалить его, потом сместить все элементы влево на один элемент.

Тогда у тебя скорее LinkedList а не массив или комбинированая стркутура 
[массив] -(указатель)->массив. А если у тебя

> да, конечно он один, id это же уникальное поле у каждого элемента, то
>   есть с таким id который передан в аргументе метода , есть только один
>   элемент.

тогда у тебя скорее Map, где int это ID, но карта неупорядоченная и сдвиать всё вправо не получится.

А самый простой способ, зная какой будет максимальный id просто иметь лукап- массив objects[] = new Object[max_id]  и добавлять objects[obj.id] = obj.